# Android JNI: How to get crash info in a c process?

Tags: android, c, crash, java-native-interface, logcat

I want to upload app crash info to my server. I start a process in C language, when the C process found the app is stopped, it collected logcat info and upload them to my server.
But I found when I used "fstream = popen("logcat -t 1000", "r")", I could not get the crash Info.

```
if(NULL == (fstream = popen("logcat -t 1000", "r")))
{
    fprintf(stderr,"execute command failed: %s",strerror(errno));
    return -1;
}
while (NULL != fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), fstream))
{
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, PUSH_LOG_TAG, "%s", buff);
    memset(buff,0,sizeof(buff));
}
```

Here is what I got in logcat of eclipse:
[image]

And here is what I got in C process:
[image]

I want to know why the "fstream = popen("logcat -t 1000", "r")" of C process can not get the DEBUG crash info.

Thanks and best wishes.

Comment: I ask a new question.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30525549/android-jni-how-to-get-all-log-messages-of-mobile-when-logcat-command-is-called

Comment: Your new question appears to be the same as this one. If you have any new information that you want to add to your question, then edit it into this one instead of posting duplicates. Other than that, you'll just have to wait for someone to provide an answer, and accept that perhaps no one is able to answer your question.